# INSERT ALL INTO and Sequence.nextval for a Surrogate Key

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert 40 rows using an INSERT ALL INTO and I'm not certain on how to insert the surrogate key. Here's what I have

```
BEGIN
   INSERT ALL 

   INTO  question(question_id)
   VALUES (question_seq.nextval)
END
```

Now if I add another INTO VALUES then I get a unique constraint violation.

```
BEGIN
   INSERT ALL 

   INTO  question(question_id)
   VALUES (question_seq.nextval)

   INTO  question(question_id)
   VALUES (question_seq.nextval)
END
```

How can I update the sequences nextval value for each  INTO VALUES so that I can avoid the unique constraint violation? I assumed that nextval would automatically update itself.

**UPDATE**: I don't know if this is the best way to handle this but here's the solution I came up with:

first I created a function that returns a value
then I called that function in the id field of the VALUES clause

```
create or replace
FUNCTION GET_QUESTION_ID RETURN NUMBER AS 
num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT UHCL_QUESTIONS_SEQ.nextval 
  INTO num 
  FROM dual;  
  return num;  
END GET_QUESTION_ID;

INSERT ALL
INTO question(question_id)
VALUES (GET_QUESTION_ID())
INTO question(question_id)
VALUES (GET_QUESTION_ID())
```

Comment: Don't you need a `from` clause with your `insert all`?

Comment: @Raihan not for the insert all.

Comment: @Raihan sorry about that...you're right, I just didn't paste the select in, but I have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
insert into question(question_id)
select question_seq.nextval from
(
    select level from dual connect by level <= 40
);
```

Although it's not a very convenient format, especially if there are other columns you want to add.  You'd probably need to create another `UNION ALL` query, and join it by the `LEVEL` or `ROWNUM`.

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
insert into question(question_id)
select question_seq.nextval value from dual
union all
select question_seq.nextval from dual;
```

But it generates `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`, due to the [restrictions on sequence values](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50944).

---

By the way, are you sure your `INSERT ALL` works without a subquery?  I get the error `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`, and the diagram from the 11.2 [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604) implies there must be a subquery:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Being from a SQL Server background, I've always created a trigger on the table to basically emulate IDENTITY functionality. Once the trigger is on, the SK is automatically generated from the sequence just like identity and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to handle this but here's the solution I came up with:

first I created a function that returns a value
then I called that function in the id field of the VALUES clause

```
create or replace
FUNCTION GET_QUESTION_ID RETURN NUMBER AS 
num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT UHCL_QUESTIONS_SEQ.nextval 
  INTO num 
  FROM dual;  
  return num;  
END GET_QUESTION_ID;

INSERT ALL
INTO question(question_id)
VALUES (GET_QUESTION_ID())
INTO question(question_id)
VALUES (GET_QUESTION_ID())
```